# The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() When removing from list by index

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to take the biggest n contours and remove the others.
But I am getting this exception in some frames and don't get it in others!
The exception happens when trying to remove a contour from the list

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/TheMaestro/Desktop/Max Planck/FishTracking/FishTracker/general_tests.py", line 93, in <module>
contours_chest = ImageProcessor.get_bigest_n_contours(contours_chest, 3)
File "/Users/TheMaestro/Desktop/Max Planck/Fish Tracking/FishTracker/Controllers/ImageProcessor.py", line 319, in get_bigest_n_contours
contours.remove(contours[i])
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

this is my code:

The call:

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img_dilated_chest, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = get_biggest_n_contours(contours, 3)
```

The function:

```
def get_biggest_n_contours(contours, n):
    contours = sorted(contours, key=get_area, reverse=True)

    contours_count = len(contours)

    if contours_count > n:
        for i in range(n,contours_count):
            contours.remove(contours[i])
            i -= 1

    return contours
```

[image: Data information]
I checked the previous answers but I don't know where to use a.any or a.all and I don't know why should I use them in my case!
I am removing using the index so I don't see a comparison that causes ambiguity!

Thank you

Comment: Actually, no I just want to know whether the count of the contours is more than n and then the loop must work! otherwise just take all the contours.

Comment: I mean I care about the contour themselves and not the values inside each contour

Comment: Please show the exact traceback that produces the warning. It's not obvious where you are using an array in a boolean context.

Comment: I have edited my question adding the complete traceback

Comment: n is an integer represents the number of contours I want
I will add the function call to the question right now

Comment: What is the shape and dtype of `contours` when it is passed into the function?

Comment: I have added the data information as a screen shot to the question

Comment: if you only want to get biggest contours you should use `cv2.findContours` method with `cv2.RETR_LIST` parameter and then get sliced list `sorted(contours, key=get_area, reverse=True)[:3]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not entirely sure about the shape of `contours` but i suspect that after your call to `sorted` you created a python list of numpy arrays.

In this line `contours.remove(contours[i])` you try to remove an element from this list of numpy arrays. The `list.remove` method does a linear search on all the elements in the `list` comparing them to the element that you want to remove. So you end up comparing numpy array to numpy array in the `remove` method and branch on the boolean value of that comparison which is ambiguous.

Instead of using `remove` (which you actually would only use if you didn't know the index of the element to remove) you could `pop` the element at that index.

But there seems to be a better alternative in your case. If i observe correctly you want to find the `n` largest entries in `contours`. That's an easy task in python when the data is sorted (which you did). So you can just slice the array after you sorted it with:

```
def get_biggest_n_contours(contours, n):
    contours = sorted(contours, key=get_area, reverse=True)

    return contours[:n]
```

The slicing will do all the work for you
1. If there are less than `n` elements just return them all
2. If there are exactly `n` elements return them all
3. If there are more just return the first `n` elements

Answer (score 1):

You should generally not remove from a list while iterating it, but this can't be right:

```
for i in range(n,contours_count):
    contours.remove(contours[i])
    i -= 1
```

The `i -= 1` will not have a real effect since the `i` in the subsequent iteration is the next elmnt from the `range`. Since it appears that you want the first `n` contours, just do:

```
contours = contours[:n]
```